# Update value only on even or odd rows using mask in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to create a new set of column with the `odd` and `even` row resulting from  `np.floor` and `np.ceil` operation, respectively.

The idea was to first  `np.floor` for all rows.Then, the output of  `np.ceil` only for the even rows.

I envision this can be done something along the code lines below

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ( [6114.26221,
                     6114.90137,
                     6145.16943,
                     6183.22803,
                     6202.06592,
                     6202.38037,
                     6202.93750,
                     6203.21387,
                     ], columns=['onset'] )
df ['round'] = df ['onset'].apply ( np.floor )

df ['round'].where ( df % 2 != 0, df ['onset'].apply ( np.ceil ) )
```

However, the compiler return

> AssertionError

Expected output

```
6114.00000
6115.00000
6145.00000
6184.00000
6202.00000
6203.00000
6202.00000
6204.00000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `numpy.where`:

```
df["round"] = np.where(df.index % 2, np.ceil(df["onset"]), np.floor(df["onset"]))
```

Output:

```
        onset   round
0  6114.26221  6114.0
1  6114.90137  6115.0
2  6145.16943  6145.0
3  6183.22803  6184.0
4  6202.06592  6202.0
5  6202.38037  6203.0
6  6202.93750  6202.0
7  6203.21387  6204.0
```